# Visual Basic - 1-100 with numbers that are divisible by 2 and 3

Tags: vb.net, loops, integer

The console seems to keep printing a repetition of the value '1'
Maybe this is because I am not incrementing the value correctly within the loop?
Or am I declaring the value of the variable in an incorrect location

```
Dim divx As Integer
    Dim divy As Integer

    divx = 1

    Do While divx < 100

        divy = divx Mod 2

        If Not (divy = 0) Then
            Console.WriteLine(divx)
        Else
            divx += 1
        End If

    Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is just to list out numbers that are divisible by 2 and 3, this should be the shortest route. Just trying to help :) If 2 or 3 then change And to Or.

```
 For x As Integer = 1 To 100
    If (x Mod 2 = 0) And (x Mod 3 = 0) Then Console.WriteLine(x)
 Next x
```

If condition is 2 and 3 but not 5 then...

```
 For x As Integer = 1 To 100
    If (x Mod 2 = 0) And (x Mod 3 = 0) And Not (x Mod 5 = 0) Then Console.WriteLine(x)
 Next x
```

Comment: This is great mate, thanks! I never realised you can set an integer from one value to another, saves me the hassle of incrementing.

Comment: Happy to help. If you know the upper limit, it's always recommended to use For Loops. If the loop depends upon a dynamic number, use While :)

Comment: Try the second solution @user3215444 :)

Comment: use 'andalso' instead of 'and' (andalso is lazy)

Comment: @chris_techno25 Thanks for that! I did manage to work it, hence why I deleted the comment. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3215444, happy to help, I learn from you, you learn from me, fair deal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are not incrementing it, you can omit the `Else`:

```
Do While divx < 100
    divy = divx Mod 2

    If Not (divy = 0) Then
        Console.WriteLine(divx)
    End If
    divx += 1
Loop
```

But if you also want to show numbers that are divisible by 3 you can modify your loop in this way:

```
Dim divx As Integer = 1
Do While divx < 100
    Dim isDivisableBy2Or3 = divx Mod 2 = 0 OrElse divx Mod 3 = 0
    If isDivisableBy2Or3 Then
        Console.WriteLine(divx)
    End If
    divx += 1
Loop
```

Comment: Great one mate! This works well...I made a slight error myself with the If rule....the not shouldn't be there as I require the mod to be 0 in order to show the values that are divisible by 2. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Do While divx < 100

    If Not (divx Mod 2 = 0) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Divisible by 2: " & divx)
    End If

    If Not (divx Mod 3 = 0) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Divisible by 3: " & divx)
    End If

    divx += 1

Loop
```

Comment: He wants it divisible by 2 **and** 3 :)

Comment: Of course, note that the same number can be divisible both by 2 and 3, so the number will be printed twice.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not give the correct values. e.g. it says that 1 is divisible by 2.

Comment: @user3215444 I Forgot to add the =0 inside the If statements. Please check it now. (I don't have a compiler here right now).